# AI Platform Pipeline 2.0.0 deployment not visible on GCP Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

On GCP, I created a new Kubernetes cluster 1.26 and deployed kubeflow pipelines 2.0.0 on it. The deployment went fine but on the AI Platform Pipeline page, I don't see the new deployment. Due to this, I am unable to open the newly deployed 2.0.0 kfp dashboard.

I tried with a public and private k8s cluster. I also tried with version 1.27 of Kubernetes and the same result. The UI of ai-platform is empty.
https://console.cloud.google.com/ai-platform/pipelines/clusters

If I go to Kubernetes > Applications, I see that my deployed application is in good health and all components are deployed properly.

Comment: I would recommend contacting Google for this You can open a case here: 

[https://cloud.google.com/contact](https://cloud.google.com/contact)

, also is Vertex AI pipeline not applicable for your use case ? As vertex ai combines other ai services into a single one and might be easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google support responded and they confirmed that there is some bug due to which the url is not visible on the console. It will be resolved soon. In the mean while, you can extract the kubeflow pipelines url using the following command

kubectl describe configmap inverse-proxy-config -n default | grep googleusercontent.com

Comment: The issue is fixed in the UI and the AI Platform pipeline is visible again.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding information about Vertex AI as a wiki for awareness :

> Data scientists can move faster with Vertex AI Platform's tools for training, tuning, and deploying ML models.

> the Kubernetes clusters and the pods running on them are managed behind the scenes by Vertex AI.

Vertex AI Page:

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai